# Invalid tag name mimekit

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, msg, mimekit

I'm using mimekit to read the content of a mhtml file. Below is snippet of my code.

```
 DirectoryInfo di = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, timeNow));
 var tmpDir = di.FullName;

 var stream = new FileStream(mhtmlfile, FileMode.Open);
 var message = MimeMessage.Load(stream);
 var visitor = new HtmlPreviewVisitor(tmpDir);
 message.Accept(visitor);
```

Currently it hit an error `System.ArgumentException: Invalid tag name. Parameter name: name` at the last line: `message.Accept(visitor);`. The error only occur for certain file. What is the error about? and how can I solve this?

Comment: The path contains slashes which are not allowed in an html tag.  So you should replace the slash in the string with another character.

Comment: If you can show me what the broken HTML looks like, I can try to fix MimeKit to work with this.